# Bounded first and second derivative on [-1,1]

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let f be a function which is twice differentiable on $\mathbb R$. Suppose that there exist $\alpha, \beta>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le \alpha$ and $|f''(x)|\le \beta$ for any $x\in [-1,1]$. Prove that $|f'(x)|\le \alpha+\beta$ for any $x\in [-1,1]$.

By applying the MVT on $f'$ I got $|{f'(x)-f'(0)\over x-0}|\le \beta $. Hence  $|f'(x)-f'(0)|\le B|x|$. It follows that for any $x\in[-1,1]$, $f'(0)-\beta \le f'(x)\le f'(0)+\beta$. However, I do not really know how to use the condition $|f(x)|\le \alpha$, and cannot figure out the proof.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume towards a contradiction that there is a point $y \in [-1, 1]$ such that $|f'(y)| > \alpha + \beta$, say $f'(y) > \alpha + \beta$ (the case $f'(y) < -\alpha-\beta$ can be treated similarly by replacing $f$ by $-f$). Since $f'$ is continuous, the strict inequality remains true in a neighborhood of $y$, so we can assume without loss of generality that $y \in (-1, 1)$.

By Taylor's theorem there is a point $w$ between $y$ and $1$ such that

$$
f(1) = f(y) + f'(y)(1-y) + \frac{f''(w)}{2}(1 - y)^2 > f(y) +(\alpha + \beta)(1-y) - \frac{\beta}{2}(1 - y)^2
$$

and a point $z$ between $-1$ and $y$ such that

$$
f(-1) = f(y) + f'(y)(-1-y) + \frac{f''(z)}{2}(-1 - y)^2 < f(y) +(\alpha + \beta)(-1-y) + \frac{\beta}{2}(-1 - y)^2 \\
\implies -f(-1) > -f(y) +(\alpha + \beta)(1+y) - \frac{\beta}{2}(1 + y)^2.
$$

Therefore we get

$$
f(1) - f(-1) > 2(\alpha + \beta) -\frac{\beta}{2}(2 + 2y^2) > 2\alpha ,
$$
in contradiction to

$$
|f(1) - f(-1)| \leq |f(1)| + |f(-1)| \leq 2\alpha.
$$